# My Null pointer exception

Tags: java, arrays, object

I am working on a simple program for my intro to Object Oriented programing class, where I have 3 classes: `Account`, `ATM` and the main/Runner class.

I am experiencing a null pointer exception error in the constructor of the `ATM` class when I am trying to initialize the array of `Account`s using a loop. I am new to Java so I don't really know what happens.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Date;
public class Account {
    private int account_id;
    private double account_balance;
    private static double annual_interest_rate;
    private Date date_Created;

    Account(){
        account_id = 0;
        account_balance=0;             
        annual_interest_rate = 0;   
        date_Created = new Date();
    }

    Account(int account_id_in, 
        double account_balance_in, double annual_interest_rate_in) {
        account_id           =  account_id_in;
        account_balance      =  account_balance_in;
        annual_interest_rate = annual_interest_rate_in;
        date_Created = new Date();
    }
    int get_account_id(){       
        return account_id;
    }
    double get_account_balance(){
        return account_balance;
    }
    double get_annual_interest_rate(){
        return annual_interest_rate;
    }
    Date get_date_created(){
        return date_Created;        
    }
    void set_account_id(int account_id_in){
        account_id = account_id_in;
    }
    void set_account_balance(double account_balance_in){
        account_balance = account_balance_in;
    }
    void set_annual_interest_rate(double annual_interest_rate_in){
        annual_interest_rate = annual_interest_rate_in;
    }
    double get_monthly_interest_rate(){     
        return annual_interest_rate/12;
    }
    double get_monthly_interest(){
        return (account_balance * get_monthly_interest_rate())/100;
    }
    void perform_deposit(double deposit_in){
        account_balance += deposit_in;
    }
    void perform_withdraw(double withdraw_amount){
        account_balance -= withdraw_amount;
    }
}



public class ATM {
    private Account[] acct = new Account [10];

    public ATM(){
        //acct = new Account[10];
        for(int i = 0; i<10 ; i++){
            acct[i].set_account_id(i+1);
            acct[i].set_account_balance(100); // here iam getting an error.
        }

        //you must set their ids to values as specified in the assignment
    }         //these are the teacher's comments and instructions.

    public void displayMenu(){
        System.out.println("ATM Menu:");
        System.out.println("\tenter 1 for viewing the current balance");
        System.out.println("\tenter 2 for withdrawing money");
        System.out.println("\tenter 3 for for depositing money");
        System.out.println("\tenter 4 for exiting the main menu");
    }

    public boolean checkID(int id){
        for(int i = 0; i<10 ; i++){
            if(acct[i].get_account_id() == id){
                return true;
            }   
        }
        return false;

    }

    public double checkBalance(int idToSearch){
        int indexOfAccountToReturn = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
            if(acct[i].get_account_id() == idToSearch){
                indexOfAccountToReturn = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return acct[indexOfAccountToReturn].get_account_balance();
    }

    public void withdrawFunds(int id, double amount){
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            if(acct[i].get_account_id() == id){
                acct[i].perform_withdraw(amount);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void depositFunds(int id, double amount){
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            if(acct[i].get_account_id() == id){
            acct[i].perform_deposit(amount);
            break;
            }
        }   
    }
}

import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Banking_Finance_Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ATM atm = new ATM();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        do{
            System.out.println("Account ID?");
            int id = input.nextInt();

            while(!(atm.checkID(id))){
                String entry = 
                                JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Incorrect Input");
                id = Integer.parseInt(entry);
            }
            //prevent user to proceed without the correct id; use checkID method and store appropriately
do{
    atm.displayMenu();
    System.out.println("Your choice?");
    int choice = input.nextInt();

    while((choice >4) || (choice <1)){
    String entry = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Incorrect Imput");
    choice = Integer.parseInt(entry);
                    }
                //prevent user to proceed without the correct choice 1-4;

    if(choice==1){
    System.out.println("Enter the Account id to check the balance: ");
    int idToSearch = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("The balance in this ACccount is: $" + atm.checkBalance(idToSearch));

    }else if(choice==2){
    System.out.println("Enter the Account id to perform withdrawal: ");
    int idToSearch = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the amount to be withdrawn: ");
    double amountToWithdraw = input.nextDouble();
    atm.withdrawFunds(idToSearch, amountToWithdraw);


    }else if(choice==3){
    System.out.println("Enter the Account id to perform deposit: ");
    int idToSearch = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the amount to be deposited: ");
    double amountToDeposit = input.nextDouble();
    atm.depositFunds(idToSearch, amountToDeposit);

    }else{
         break;
    }

    }while(true);
        }while(true);
    }

}
```

I am sorry if I am using this site inappropriately, this is my first question here so bear with me please.
I managed to pass through the error with the following fix:

```
public ATM(){
    for(int i = 0; i<10 ; i++){
        acct[i] = new Account();
        acct[i].set_account_id(i+1);
        acct[i].set_account_balance(100);
    }

    //you must set their id's to values as specified in the assignment
}
```

However I am not sure if this is correct or not. Is it?

Comment: what is the exact error message you get (stack trace including line number, and point out what line that is in your code)

Comment: What would be the best way to initialize the Account array?

Comment: side note: Best practice methods and variables names should be in mixed case, remove underscore.

Comment: that is the correct answer. please accept the answer from which you implemented it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beside creating array you also need to fill it with objects. Update your code in ATM constructor:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    acct[i] = new Account(); // add this line to crate account
                             // and place it in array
    acct[i].set_account_id(i + 1); // also you are getting error here
    acct[i].set_account_balance(100); // not here because you ware trying to 
                                      // invoke method on `null`
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that this line:

`private Account[] acct = new Account [10];`

only initializes space for 10 Account instances, it doesn't actually construct 10 account instances and put them in the array.

In the for loop in your ATM constructor, you need to first call acct[i] = new Account();

Comment: I managed to pass through the null pointer error, with the suggested fixes:                                                                                                                                                                                                                public ATM(){
  for(int i = 0; i<10 ; i++){
   acct[i] = new Account();
   acct[i].set_account_id(i+1);
   acct[i].set_account_balance(100);
  }

 }